# C++ VS Fatal error C1083 Permission denied

Tags: c++, fatal-error, permission-denied

I have searched for hours online trying to find a solution. I'm new to C++, however I've compiled quite a few programs and never had any trouble until last night.

I'm using the Microsoft VS command prompt. I've tried this on 2010, 12, and 13, and get the same error... as well as on 2 different computer systems. I thought it may be a code issue, however, I just typed up a simple program that I know will work, yet I get the same error. I'm running Windows 8 64 bit

From the command prompt I enter cl C:\Users\David\Desktop\1\simplecpp.cpp

and get the following error:

> C:\Users\David\Desktop\1\simplecpp.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'simplecpp.obj': Permission denied

I can get the programs to compile if I run as Administrator (what I read on another post) However, there is no output. It doesn't save the object or program files. I have also checked permissions, and everything is correct.

Neither computer has had anything changed, both do use ad-aware, however, I disabled that and tried just in case something was interfering, but still it doesn't work. I also turned off my firewall and tried. I find it odd that both of my computers at the same time are experiencing the same issue?

Comment: You may find better help on forums dedicated to Windows administration.

Comment: Thanks...I'll post this on a windows board.

Comment: If the file already exists and is owned by the administrator, attempts to overwrite them will be denied by the OS. Now, you say it doesn't write the file, but I think you are mistaken. Instead, it tries to write the file in a location you don't expect instead! In any case, you should be able to work with MSVS without admin privileges.

Comment: I've tried new files, files I know don't exist and still have the same problem. Also tried using a different directory, and media also. I've searched my entire computer for the output files that compile when I run as Administrator, and not able to find those either. Seems like a privilege issue, but I don't know where to go from here. Nothing I do seems to change anything.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found out what the problem was. I don't know how it happened, but somehow, my Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 folder permissions for my master account got reset on both of my computers and I didn't have permissions to modify any files. This is the case for other versions I had installed as well.

Possibly a windows update issue? Anyhow, I reset permissions to allow full access, and all is working now!

If anyone else comes across this and is having the same issue, just navigate to your Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 folder "...Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" > right click and go to Properties > Click security tab > Click Edit, then the affected user and check full control.

It is, however, saving my project files to the root Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 folder now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look for other instances of Visual Studio which may have that file open still.  Close them if you find them.  If all else fails, reboot the machine -- Windows is very fussy about open files!

Comment: Thanks, but I have done that as well. There are no instances of the file open.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set msdev.exe located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin to run in Win XP, SP3 compatibility mode for all users to fix this issue. It was already set to run as admin for all users.

Answer (score 0):

You also can run into this issue when you attempt to build a release. My old release was still in the release folder and I made one of the files hidden. It gave me this error and I couldn't figure out why but, if you make that file unhidden again it, resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

I use VS2019 meet this problem, and finally I found out the reason.

- When I first add(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) a class file call `[MyClass].cpp` to my project, VS will auto add CPP to project's `.vcxproj.filter`,
- and made them in `ClCompile` block.
- Then I changed CPP to HEADER `[MyClass].h`.

By do this, VS doesn't re-organize all files in `.vcxproj.filters` except path, so HEADER file is still in `ClCompile` block, this cause the problem.

To solve, simple delete the file from project and re-add it